# Loop through subfolder move only specific file to another folder using python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to loop between these subfolders and move only http.log file to another folder.

```
target_folder = new_folder_with_http
source_folder = original_data

for path, dir, files in os.walk(source_folder):
if files == 'http.log':
os.move(target_folder):
else skip
```

please help me with this code

Comment: `if 'http.log' in files:` I think would solve most of your problem

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Again, please post a new question if you have a new problem with code from one of the answers.

Comment: I rolled back your changes again. Please don't change your question to be about a different topic, especially after you have received answers to the original question. If you have a new problem, post a new question. (Also, for the love of `gvr`, indent your Python code so it's not one giant syntax error.)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is only to find a single `http.log` file somewhere in the source folder and move it to the target folder, you can use `pathlib.Path.glob()` to do the work of finding, then just move the first one it finds:

```
import pathlib

target_folder = pathlib.Path('new_folder_with_http')
source_folder = pathlib.Path('original_data')

found_files = list(source_folder.glob('**/http.log'))

found_files[0].rename(target_folder / 'http.log')
```

Answer (score -1):

`files` is a list; you want to check if this file name is a member.

```
target_folder = new_folder_with_http

for path, dir, files in os.walk(original_data):
    if "http.log" in files:
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(path, "http.log"),
            os.path.join(target_folder, "http.log"))
```

There is no `os.move`; I guess you want `os.rename` or perhaps `shutil.move`.

Notice also how we need to prefix the `path` (the directory it was found in) back in front of the bare file name.

The `else` clause is optional; just don't put one if you don't have any code to put there.

The same file name can only exist once in `targetdir` so this will fail on Windows if it finds multiple files with the same name. On Unix, or if you switch to `shutil.move`, it will replace all the found files in `targetdir` with the last one found. If you don't want either of those things to happen, you'll have to specify a way to make each file name unique after moving, perhaps by renaming it to reflect which directory it was found in somehow.

Here is a simple loop to add a numeric suffix if the file already exists:

```
    ...
    if "http.log" in files:
        dest = os.path.join(target_folder, "http.log"))
        suf = None
        while os.path.exists(dest):
            if suf is None:
                suf = 1
            else:
                suf += 1
            dest = os.path.join(target_folder, "http.log." + str(suf))
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(path, "http.log"),
            dest)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! When using this code it giving me Error saying that the file can not create when that file already exists. I think it is because each folder contains one http.log file. What's the solution?

Comment: The answer already discusses this and available workarounds; did you not read all of it? The real lesson is to not use Windows, I suppose (-:

Comment: Seriously, though, your question doesn't reveal what should happen in this situation, and I didn't want to second-guess your requirements. One simple way to solve that is to add a numeric suffix and increment it until you reach a file name which doesn't already exist. Perhaps (accept this answer and) ask a new question if it's not obvious how to do that (but search before asking; it has been solved many times before).

Comment: Can you please show me how to add a numeric suffix and increment? I appreciate your help!

Comment: And you searched before asking? See update now.